# Auto accepting contacts using phpmsnclass

Tags: php, class, msn

I'm currently using [phpmsnclass](http://code.google.com/p/phpmsnclass/) to send messages to contacts on the MSN network. But to get the nickname on my "bot" to work I have to accept the "friend-request" my contacts has sent me.

From the debuginfo I have found that around line 1672 in the file msn.clas.php it's a kind of auto-accepting feature. But I cant use the doLoop function that has this feature cause it never ends.

So is there anyone who has time to check this out for me, or have another framework for working with msn that may be better on this? Have read about the MSN Network a lot now, but I haven't got the knowledge of doing this out of my own mind, I need some hints.

In advance: thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of how you would go about this but have you thought of a two part check? One that runs while the program is active, and then while it it active check to see if the feature someone is trying to add the bot. If someone is then proceed to auto accept. This would require a response time though. I hope the pseudo-code below, as rough as it is, helps at least a bit.

```
while (program is running) 
   if (pendingRequest == true){
        doSomething
   }
}
```